# linux bluetooth low energy source code

Tags: linux, bluetooth, linux-kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy

After surfing the net, could not able to find, the source code of bluetooth low energy implementation in the linux.

does bulez implements already? Kindly advice.

Comment: http://www.bluez.org/bluez-low-energy-support-status/

Answer (score 3):

I came to the same conclusion that at this point there is no standard "ready to use solution".

One option is to use a  Bluetooth 4.0 USB Dongle such as the [Bluegiga BLED112 dongle](http://www.bluegiga.com/BLED112_Bluetooth_low_energy_dongle). The dongle basically implements the full BLE stack and is recognized by the system as a serial port (a ttyACM device in linux). There is a binary protocol over the serial port to interact with the bluetooth stack (configure, connect to devices, etc).

Bluegiga provides a C API for the binary protocol and there is an open-source [Java implementation of it](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/bglib). We are using both with linux without problems.